# Signalr hub connection management in client winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, signalr

I'm looking for advice on how best to handle Signalr hub connections in a winforms app acting as the client.

I have a web app as the Signalr (v0.5.1) server and a client winforms app using hubs. Everything works as desired, I just feel I have too many Signalr connections to the server.  For each form I am creating a new `HubConnection` instance because the [hub needs to subscribe to events before the connection is started](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs).  One or two hubs are used on each form and not all forms subscribe to server events, some just invoke server-side methods.

Can I have one (static) `HubConnection` (eg a property of the Program) and use it for all forms?  This strategy implies start/stop/state management hassles as each form may subscribe to different events.

What's the best strategy for managing Signalr connections (and hubs) in a .Net client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you only need one connection for your entire application. How you choose to store that is up to you (static vs DI etc).

Comment: Thanks.  How should I handle the scenario where different forms subscribe to different server-side events, do I need to set up all possible subscriptions before the connection is started?  This would require instantiating all forms using the connection, even if the form is not not used/shown.

Comment: That was the case before but not in 0.5.1. You only need to tell Signalr which hubs you care about before starting the connection.

Comment: Great.  I've only just upgraded from 0.4.x and haven't caught up with the detailed changes yet.

Comment: @dfowler should the HubProxy be created every time or can this also be a single instance?